# Acceleration sensor in HTC phone

Tags: accelerometer

Does anyone know which acceleration sensor was used in the HTC Touch Diamond mobile phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is the [KXSD9](http://www.kionix.com/accelerometers/accelerometer-KXSD9.html) from Kionix

Comment: Can you cite your sources?

Comment: Yes Joby. http://cellphonerepairtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/05/familarization-components-and-parts-on_9689.html

Comment: Muito obrigado! :-)

Comment: De nada. Do you speak Portuguese @stevenvh?

Comment: @o engenheiro: only what I look up :-). But I figured from your nick that you would be portuguese/brasilian, which was confirmed when I looked at your profile.