# What is the most common type of accelerometers in today's smartphones?

Tags: accelerometer, android, iphone

I know there are [6 different types of sensors for measuring acceleration](http://www2.usfirst.org/2005comp/Manuals/Acceler1.pdf):

- Capacitive
- Piezoelectric
- Piezoresistive
- Hall Effect
- Magnetoresistive
- Heat transfer-based

I have trouble finding a source that can help me find out what kind of accelerometer that is being used in today's smartphones.

I think it is piezoelectric according to [source](http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/wiki/images/Zeitmaschinen-smartphonesensors.pdf), but its not a good one. Is there any better source that can confirm this in a more statistical or official manner?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [iPhone uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer) LIS302DL, capacitive. The [Samsung Galaxy 2
   uses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11372/samsung-galaxy-s-accelerometer-details) SMB380, capacitive. The [HTC Touch Diamond uses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/acceleration-sensor-in-htc-phone) KXSD9,
   capacitive.

Some [market share](http://www.isuppli.com/mems-and-sensors/news/pages/accelerometers-set-to-become-leading-mems-device-in-2013.aspx) [information](http://www.eetimes.com/design/analog-design/4019530/MEMS-accelerometers-a-fast-track-to-design-success-) on MEMS devices.